# I want to enable a beep sound on my laptop for my charger

Tags: sound, power-management, battery, charging

Laptop BIOS settings used to have the option to enable a beep when the charger is plugged or unplugged. From what I can gather, 99% of people hated this. I, however find it useful.

My BIOS does not have such an option and I'm looking for a way to add a background process on my Ubuntu that makes a beep whenever the charger is plugged or unplugged. Can anyone offer some pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're running Ubuntu Desktop 20.04, it should beep when power is connected or disconnected. If it doesn't, then there are a few things you'll need to check:

**1 — Sound Settings**

1. Open "Settings" and click on the *Sounds* tab.
2. Confirm that "System Sounds" is not muted and is loud enough to be heard

[image: System Sounds]

If everything there is correct, then ...

**2 — Gnome Power Panel**

1. Open "dconf Editor" and navigate to: org / gnome / desktop / notifications / application / gnome-power-panel
2. Confirm that `enabled` is enabled
3. Confirm that `enable-sound-alerts` is enabled

[image: dconf Editor]

If you do not have dconf Editor on your system, you can install it like this:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Hopefully this will help you get the audio confirmation for when power is connected and disconnected

Comment: Thanks! This was very useful, it worked!